# Can't open a file using C++

Tags: c++, file-io, xcode6

I have a file called 'matrixA'; it's a text file. It's in a folder called "assignments". I have another file called main.cpp also in the assignments folder.

```
ifstream myfile ("matrixA");

string linebuffer;
if (!myfile.is_open()){
    cout << "error";
}
```

It always outputs error.

What is going on? Why can't I open the file?

Comment: Either the file isn't named `matrixA` (`matrixA.txt` perhaps?), or you are not running your program in the same directory as the text file (the location of `main.cpp` is irrelevant).

Comment: Switch to the folder where your `matrixA` file is, then run: `/the/full/or/relative/path/to/your/program`

Comment: /Users/mystuff/cx4220/cx4220/cx4220/assignments/matmult.cpp                          /Users/mystuff/cx4220/cx4220/cx4220/assignments/matrixA.                          These are the two full paths.

Comment: What is the exact error? Where is the binary file from the .cpp file created?

Comment: it just doesn't open.

Comment: @user678392 You seem to think that your program will execute in the same directory as `main.cpp`. Your code will look for `matrixA` in the *current working directory* which is wherever you are running the program from, and by the sounds of things is a completely different location to that of `matrixA`.

Comment: @user678392 there is also another possibility isn't the file already opened by another program with exclusive rights or corrupted? try to open it in notepad or whatever if it can be opened. Also to check the working directory you can create a file with specific name and then search it on the disc where it was created ... Also if you using some old file DOS style access style then the filename and path can not exceed 66 characters ... hard to say how it is on Linux (I am more of a Win guy)

Answer (score 1):

Try use absolute path for matrixA. or run your program in folder assignments.

You can tell where your program run by call to getcwd.

Answer (score 1):

See, it all depends on where your executable file is.
If it is in the same folder as your `matrixA` file is, you just need to give `ifstream myfile("matrixA");`.

But if your executable file is not in the same folder as the `matrixA` file, it would be better to give the **absolute path** for the file, in your case, the code should be :

```
ifstream myfile("/Users/jsuit/cx4220/cx4220/cx4220/assignments/matrixA");
```

It is always advisable to give the absolute path for opening a file, as you do not know from which location your executable file could be run.

Comment: I can't use the absolute path. I'm just going to give up on Xcode. It's making things incredibly difficult.

Comment: This isn't working? Please post the exact error with the full source then. We'd be glad to help.

Comment: the full path works, i just can't use it. I need to use a relative path.

Comment: Okay. Let us try a workaround. Are you sure that the relative path between the executable file and the read file will always be same? If yes, then you should go for the relative path.

Comment: Here's what is going on: I'm using Xcode to run some c++ code. I need to give that code (part of bigger project) to someone else later on. I want to use a relative path because "/Users/jsuit/ ..." isn't going to be there on someone else's computer. They will running it from the command line.

Comment: I understand your dilemma. But then, you will have to specify in the README file to maintain the relative path. Or, you would have to do a series of checks if the `matrixA` file is present in the current directory. If not, you would have to scan it in all the directories, resulting in a lot of dirty code. The best bet here would be to let the other user know the relative positions between both the files. Then, the relative path usage would be best.

Comment: What is relative path?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69268/discussion-between-shaurya-chats-and-user678392).

Answer (score 1):

After you compile your cpp file, you'll get an executable file, may be called **main.exe**. I guess **main.exe** and **matrixA** is not in the same directory, that's why you always get outputs error.

Try to use absolute path or something like `../matrixA`.

Comment: Check your Xcode project directory, can you find an executable file named **main**? Make sure your **matrixA** is in that directory.

Comment: I found the executable. But xcode won't let me move the executable or move any folders into that folder.

Comment: Just put **matrixA** in that folder by Finder, not Xcode.

Comment: It doesn't show up. You can look at everything besides the executable in Finder. Or you can look at the folder with the executable. You can't do both.

Comment: Or you can calculate the relevant path from the executable.

Comment: Could you give me your executable file absolute path and **matrixA** absolute path?

Comment: I think I found a method to solve your problem.  open Xcode, click `command + ,`, click `location`, find derived data, click `advanced`, choose `Custom` and choose `Relative to Workspace`. After doing that, `command + B` build your project, you will find a folder called `Build`, your executable file is in `Build/Products/Debug/`. So I think the relevant path should be: `../../../assignments/matrixA`